# react custom hook change input value and show it on other component

Tags: reactjs

I have three react files

useUser.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const useUser = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState();
  const [showProfile, setShowProfile] = useState();

  return { username, setUsername, showProfile, setShowProfile };
};

export default useUser;
```

2nd file is Login.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import useUser from "../customHooks/useUser";

const Login = () => {
  const { setUsername, setShowProfile } = useUser();

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="m-2 p-2"
          placeholder="Enter your email here"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setUsername(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="m-2 p-2"
          placeholder="Enter your password here"
          onChange={(e) => {}}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button
          className="m-2 p-2"
          onClick={() => {
            setShowProfile(true);
          }}>
          Login
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

and then Profile.js

```
    import React from "react";

const Profile = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-3xl">Profile</h1>
      <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold">username: </h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

and then contact

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Login from "../components/Login";
import Profile from "../components/Profile";
import useUser from "../customHooks/useUser";

const contact = () => {
  const { username, showProfile } = useUser();
  return (
    <div>
      <Login></Login>
      {showProfile && <Profile />}
      <div>username is : {username}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default contact;
```

I want to update the value of username input in the login and use the custom userUser hook to set the username and setShowprofile and use the vcalue to show profile or hide it. is it possible or i need to use the useContext hook as well. I was trying to avoid the useContext hook. thanks.

Comment: You will need to either use a parent component to pass the data into `Profile` and `Login` or use a `Provider`

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options. The simplest solution is to have your `Contact` component, which is the parent component of both `Login` and `Profile`, be the consumer of the `useUser` hook and pass that into `Login` and `Profile`

```
const Contact = () => {
  const { username, setUsername, showProfile, setShowProfile } = useUser();

  return (
    <div>
      <Login setShowProfile={setShowProfile} setUsername={setUsername} />
      {showProfile && <Profile username={username} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The second option is to use the [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook. This is slightly more involved and I'd recommend not using it in this case unless your use case becomes more involved. [Here's a good blog post](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively) on what it might look like

Comment: thanks tom, this is my first question on stackoverflow and i got answered like within like an hour thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of you using your `useUser` hook results in a different set of states managed by different components.

You either need to create this state at a common anchestor of all your components in the react tree and pass the relevant functions and values down via props or use some kind of state management for your whole application.

The relevant part of the react docs seems to be [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

I'd suggest starting with the common anchestor approach for reasonable small applications and having a look at other alternatives ([redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) comes to mind) when this get's to tedious.